# Testing url redirection in Django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/login/`, login form will be displayed and you have to input `username` and `password`. If the credentials are right then you will be redirected to `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/`. The problem I am facing while testing is even though my `username` and `password` are correct it is not redirected to `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/` but rather it goes to `http://testserver/admin/login/?next=/dashboard/`. I am using the below code to rest redirection functionality in django:

```
class UrlTests(TestCase):

    def test_client_cart(self):
        response = self.client.get('/login/')
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)

    def test_login_client(self):
        User.objects.create_user('rakesh', 'rrs402@nyu.edu', 'ranjan')
        self.client.get('/login/')
        self.client.login(username='rakesh', password='ranjan')
        print self.client.get('/dashboard/')
```

Could anyone tell me why i am redirected to `http://testserver/admin/login/?next=/dashboard/` instead `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/`.

In my `settings.py` file:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

My application is working fine but I am not able to test redirection thing. Could anyone give me some pointers where I am going wrong?

If I print out `print self.client.login(username='rakesh', password='ranjan')` it is coming out to be `True` which means I am able to login but why not redirection ?

Update : I also tried using selenium

```
def login_user(self):
        # User opens his web browser, and goes to the website
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/login/')
        # User types in his username and passwords and hits return
        username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        username_field.send_keys('rakesh')
        password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        password_field.send_keys('ranjan')
        #User submits the form
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        print body.text
```

Here also I am getting the body.text of `admin` page but not `dashboard` page.

Update :

Dashboard view :

```
class PortalDashboardView(RequireStaffMixinView, TemplateView):
    template_name = "portal/dashboard.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't getting logged in. The password you are sending to the login call is different to the one you use when creating the user within your test case, so the credentials are invalid.

Note you don't need to call `client.get('/login/')` there, anyway.

Comment: I updated my question with selenium code please check!

Comment: If I don't call `client.get('/login/')` then you can't go `dashboard` since only authenticated users are allowed.

Comment: Not true. You login with `self.client.login(...)`. In the test, you don't need to visit the page first.

Comment: I tried with just `self.client.login(...)` but then again I am redirected to `http://testserver/admin/login/?next=/dashboard/`. What do you think is happening ?

Comment: In my application if I put proper `username` and `password`, I am redirected to `\dashboard` page.

Comment: You should probably post the code for the dashboard view. Exactly how are you enforcing authentication there?

Comment: I have added the dashboard view but there is really nothing there.

Comment: Sigh, the interesting part is obviously RequireStaffMixinView. Just the name implies that you require a user with `is_staff` set to True; is that the case, and if so have you tried setting that attribute on the user you create in the test?

Comment: Are you talking about `RequireStaffMixinView()` ? Could you elaborate your comment

Comment: I should do this then `User.objects.create_user('rakesh', 'rrs402@nyu.edu', 'ranjan', is_staff=True)` right?

Comment: No, annoyingly that doesn't work; you'd either need to use `create_superuser` which also sets is_superuser, or get the user and manually set `user.is_staff=True` then save it.

Comment: Hey Daniel, create_superuser worked :D :D Thank you so much sir